# Ubuntu 18.10 & AMD RX 580. Flicker screen artifacts

Tags: flicker

After installing the operating system constant flicker. [Video](https://youtu.be/d_LXHqWKTbk)

Answer (score 1):

I have RX480 that also flicker, for now my solution is to use an older kernel 4.18.0-11-generic.

You can boot to this kernel version in GRUB

Comment: This is the only solution at the moment, the bug doesn t on kernels from version 4.18.10 to 4.18.12. Join the ticket https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/+bug/1813701 The more people report a problem, the faster the problem will be solved.